# How to iterate Data from two columns into single select box in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am doing it in old fashioned way like without using any model.
I want to get price and Name columns from same table and show the Name in Selectbox options and whenever user selects an option its price should come into a label on the side. It is loading Names but dont know how to get the price.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Controller Code:**

```
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        List<string> listId = new List<string>();
        List<string> listName = new List<string>();
        List<string> listPrice = new List<string>();


        conn.Open();
        string query = "select id,pkgName,price from packages";
        SqlCommand cmdss = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmdss.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            listId.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            listName.Add(dr[1].ToString());
            listPrice.Add(dr[2].ToString());


        }

        conn.Close();

        var ListNameArray = listName.ToArray();
        ViewBag.ListNameArray = ListNameArray;

        var ListPriceArray= listPrice.ToArray();
        ViewBag.ListPriceArray = ListPriceArray;

        return View();
```

**View Code:**

```
<select>

         @foreach (string item in ViewBag.ListNameArray)
         {
           <option>@item</option>
         }

</select>
```

Comment: do you want to name and price same field like this "Coco $610" ?

Comment: You only need one list, something like List<Tuple<string, string>>, Populate each Tuple with name and price.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class to represent each package record.

```
public class Package
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public decimal Price { set; get; }       
}
```

Now when you read the table, create a list of this class and add an object to this list for each record.

```
var list=new List<Package>();
using(SqlDataReader dr = cmdss.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (dr.Read())
   {
        var p = new Package();
        p.Id=reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id"));
        p.Name=reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("pkgName"));
        p.Price=reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("Price"));
        list.Add(p);
   }
}
```

Assuming `Id` is of type Int an `Price` is of decimal type.

So now create a view model for your view

```
public class PackageVm
{
  public List<Package> Packages { set;get;}
  public int SelectedPackage { set;get;}
}
```

Now in the GET action, create an object of this, Load the `Packages` property to the list and send it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var vm=new PackageVm();
  vm.Packages = GetPackages();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Assuming GetPackages method returns the list of Package ( the prev method).

Now in your view, which is strongly typed to your PackageVm class, Use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method to render the dropdown. Also We will store this list of Packages to a javascript array which we will use later. When user changes the dropdown, read the selected item value ( Id) and loop through the packages array and compare the Id's. If it is matching, get the Price property of that item and show it in the label.

```
@model PackageVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedPackage,new SelectList(Model.Packages,"Id","Name"))
  <label id="price">Test</label>
  <input type="submit" />
}
@section Scripts
{
   $(function() {

     var packages = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Packages));
     $("#SelectedState").change(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $.each(packages, function(a, b) {
                if (b.Id == val) {
                    $("#price").html(b.Price);                        
                }
            });
     });
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your response. As I am new to MVC and Entity framework. Can u please tell me the above reader portion will to controller or to the Package class or to the model?

Comment: You should put that in your GetPackages method. It can stay in your controller or a seperate data access class. It is your call. All you need to make sure is , It returns a `List<Package>`

Comment: Thanks bro. Having definition not found Error at SelectedState on the view. what to do?

Comment: Sorry It should be `SelectedPackage`. Fixed

Comment: Yes. It is fixed. Thank u very much. Little more help plz. Its just not getting price into Test Label. plz

Comment: Does your label has Id "price". Is the if condition returning true for any record ? `put a console.log("val :"+ val+", item id:"+ b.Id)` inside the $.each loop and see the values.

Comment: Values are being received in "@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Packages))" but each loop is not working. Nothing comes in console. Its not even showing any alert on selection change. Its not going into loop I thnk

Comment: Make sure you do not have any other script error in your page. Check your browser console.