# Possible to retrieve data from viewbag with where condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to retrieve images on basis of property id.

What I am doing is getting all the property text data in one view bag says `ViewBag.tblProperty` and I am retrieving all the images in another viewbag as `ViewBag.tblImages`.

This is my code:

```
@foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.tblProperty.Rows)
{     
    <ul class="popup-gallery-@dr["PropertyID"] bxslider-@dr["PropertyID"]">
    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.tblimages.where(@dr["PropertyID"]).Rows)
    { 
        <li><a href="@dr["FileName"]"><img src="@dr["FileName"]" /></a></li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

I want to retrieve images from `ViewBag.tblImages` on basis of `PropertyID` getting from `ViewBag.tblProperty`.

How can I do so?

Comment: This seems like an abuse of `ViewBag`. `DataTables` are not strongly typed, and on top of that, you are assigning them to `ViewBag`. Convert the `Datatable` to a list in the controller and then use them in the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag is dictionary which stores item as dynamic type. So you need to first convert that to a `DataTable` and can use `AsEnumerable` method to convert your data table to a list of anonymous objects which you can use later with a `Where` clause

Assuming your tblImages has an `Id`,`FileName` and `ParentId` properties

```
@{
    var imgsDt = ViewBag.tblimages as DataTable;
    var imageList = imgsDt.AsEnumerable().Select(t => new
    {
        Id = t.Field<int>("Id"),
        FileName= t.Field<string>("FileName"),
        ParentId = t.Field<int>("ParentId"),
    }).ToList();
}
@foreach (var dr in ViewBag.tblProperty.Rows)
{
    var id = (int) dr["Id"];

    <div>
        <span>@dr["Name"]</span>
        @foreach (var imgItem in imageList.Where(d=>d.ParentId== id))
        {
            <div>@imgItem.FileName</div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

You need to add `@using System.Data` to the top of your view.

For simplicity, i updated the markup to just print the name/property values inside a div. you can update that part to your markup (ul-li)

**While this might fix the issue, I strongly recommend you to not use DataTables with ViewBag to transfer data**. The code is going to be hard to maintain. I suggest you create a view model class and load the data to the view model in your action method and send the view model to the view. This way your view will not have any idea what sort of data access you are using and it is going to be very clean and readable.

You can use `SqlDataReader` if you are writing custom ado.net code. Create a POCO class representing your entities and assign to that. There are tons of samples on internet about that.

Comment: You also need to add `using System.Data`

Comment: Here is a sample post about getting data via DataReader and custom POCO class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092862/how-to-iterate-data-from-two-columns-into-single-select-box-in-asp-net-mvc/37093256#37093256 ( Just the first part)

Comment: can u explain how to pass view model as an example

Comment: Thanks for advice but as I m new I don't know how to use viewmodel

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3 There are tons of samples on the internet if you do a google search